# Plotting sequential Bayes factor as participants are added

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

I'm analyzing EEG data by using a sequential Bayes factor approach, and would like to make a plot showing how the Bayes factor changes as participants are added. I started out using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144341/how-to-plot-a-sequential-bayes-factor-as-participants-are-added), but it doesn't work for me, perhaps because I'm doing a paired t-test?

The code I've tried is the following:

```
srange.F3A <- 10:nrow(BFData_new)
BF <- sapply(srange.F3A, function(i) {
  extractBF(ttestBF(x=BFData_new$A_F3_gram, y=BFData_new$A_F3_Ugram, paired = TRUE[1:i]), onlybf=TRUE)
})

plot(srange.F3A, BF)
```

However, this produces the following error message:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extractBF': the condition has length > 1

Can someone please help me with how I can fix this?
Thanks a lot!